# Using Apache POI to write in xlsx file, Getting expected answer in the last column of the file

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am learning how to write in the xlsx file using Apache poi,Now in the below code i am using 2 array.
1.Month 2.Logging_Hours.

I am using Month array to assign the column name in the first row and it work fine for me.Now what i want the another Array in my code Logging_Hours print in each column but i am not getting the expected answer by using the below code.

For_Expected refer to the screen :"Expected_Xlsx"
For_Actual refer to the screen :"Actual_Xlsx"

```
public class Writing_xlsx {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();

    Sheet sheet1=wb.createSheet("SheetOne");

    String [] Month={"January" , "Feb", "March","Apr"};
    int [] Logging_Hours={ 7 ,5, 9,10};
    int f=0;
    System.out.println(Month[0]);

    Row r=sheet1.createRow(f);

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){

    r.createCell(i).setCellValue(Month[i]);   

    }

    for(int c=0;c<4;c++){}
        int d=0;
        while(d<4){

        for(int rn=1;rn<=4;rn++)    {

            r=sheet1.createRow(rn);
            r.createCell(d).setCellValue(Logging_Hours[rn-1]);
            System.out.println(Logging_Hours[rn-1]);

        }
        d++;
        }

        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xlsx");

    wb.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();    
    wb.close();

}

}
```

For_Expected refer to the screen :"Expected_Xlsx"

[image: This is the expected screen after running the programm]

For_Actual refer to the screen :"Actual_Xlsx"

[image: This is the actual screen i am getting]

Thank You in advance ,Sorry for the bad code i am just in a learning phase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need two `for` loops (nested) to write the data, e.g.:

```
for (int rn = 1; rn <= 4; rn++) {
    Row row = sheet1.createRow(rn);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        row.createCell(i).setCellValue(Month[rn-1]);
    }
}
```

Current `for` loop creates only one `cell` per row and writes the value into it whereas we need to write the values in all 4 cells per row.

Comment: ,This is the another answer i want to print the Logging_Hours in each column like Column A: 7,5,9,10

What your suggestion did: Column A:7,7,7,7

Comment: @balvinderdhillon this is in line with "Expected Answer" in your question.

Comment: please see it carefully its different.......My expected code give o/p in column A:7,5,9,10

Comment: Can it be done by typing column value ? like in column A first no row wise

Comment: It can be done. However, the logic will be a bit complicated as POI works well with rows. Also, in your code, there was only one for loop (I have mentioned that in my answer) that's why it only printed one column.

Comment: Thank you for your help and time :)